# Prove or disprove, Span

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a vector space, $M, N \subset V $sets.
Prove or disprove:

i) span($M$) $\cap$ span($N$) = Span(M$\cap$N)

ii) let $u,v$ be $\in$ V. Then: Span$(u,v) = $span$(u,u+v)$

I'm sorry, but for i) I can't give any steps, so please point me in the right way.

ii) is ture I think: two cases. First u,v can be linear dependent. Then span$(u)=$span$(v)=$span$(u+v)=$span$(u,u+v). $Second u,v can be linear independent. Then $u,u+v $are still linear independent as per definition of linear dependency, and span$(u,v)=$span$(u,u+v)$

I'm not sure about this either, though... Any help and pointers are gladly welcome!!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A counterexample for the first question is $V=\mathbf R$, $M= \{1\}$ and $N=\{2\}$, that verify $span(M)=span(N)=V$ but $span(M\cap N)= \{0\}$.